# Pass dynamic variables through to form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using a lightbox to load a single form, however I'd like to be able to pass through different variables to the form as hidden values depending on which 'Remind Me' link has been clicked.

I'd like to pass through the product title, release date and product link as these will all get stored in a MySQL table alongside the name, email address and reminder date. These are all PHP variables in my code which is set up like this:

```
 <div class="column third">
    <div class="featcontainer">
    <figure class="image-container"><div class="featimage">                     
    <img src="<?=$row['img_url']?>"/></div>
    <figcaption class="clearfix">
    <h3><?=$row['small_title']?></h3>
    <div class="release_date"><?=$row['release_date']?></div>
    <a href="<?=$row['prod_link']?>" class="btn1" target="_blank">Product Link</a>
    <a href="" class="remindme" target="_blank">Remind Me</a>
    </figcaption>
    </figure>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The outputted HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="column third">
    <div class="featcontainer">
    <figure class="image-container">
            <div class="featimage">Image here</div>
    <figcaption class="clearfix">
        <h3>Product 1 Title</h3>
    <div class="release_date">Release Date Here</div>
    <a href="Link 1" class="btn1" target="_blank">Product Link</a>
    <a href="" class="remindme" target="_blank">Remind Me</a>
    </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column third">
    <div class="featcontainer">
    <figure class="image-container">
    <div class="featimage">Image here</div>
    <figcaption class="clearfix">
    <h3>Product 2 Title</h3>
    <div class="release_date">Release Date Here</div>
    <a href="Link 2" class="btn1" target="_blank">Product Link</a>
    <a href="" class="remindme" target="_blank">Remind Me</a>
    </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column third">
    <div class="featcontainer">
    <figure class="image-container">
    <div class="featimage">Image here</div>
    <figcaption class="clearfix">
    <h3>Product 3 Title</h3>
    <div class="release_date">Release Date Here</div>
    <a href="Link 3" class="btn1" target="_blank">Product Link</a>
    <a href="" class="remindme" target="_blank">Remind Me</a>
    </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
</div>

<form class="remindme" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text">  
<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text">  
<label>When to remind</label>
<input type="radio" id="date" name="date" value="ondate">On Release
<input type="radio" id="date" name="date" value="beforedate">Day Before Release
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Remind Me" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried the `<ipnut type="hidden">` tag?
You can use it like this:

(Inside your form)

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="prod_title" value="<?= row['prod_title'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="release_date" value="<?= row['release_date'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="prod_link" value="<?= row['prod_link'] ?>" />
...
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Check this Fiddle where I wrote you an example.  When the user clicks a link, it gets the desired details (link, title, date) from an array and sets them in the hidden inputs at the form: http://jsfiddle.net/W5L2D/

The arrays should be created with PHP iteration, and also put the numbers in the link's name attribute.

Comment: Wouldn't this involve coding the form for every single product iteration? As the PHP variable won't be passed to the form on click, it'll already be set when the page loads to the final product pulled from the database.

Comment: @jacobgibbs then you should output all the information (title, release date and link) in a javascript array from PHP, and detect with jacascript which link has been clicked and update the value of the hidden inputs.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any examples or links I can look at? I'm happy to give it a go myself but I'm still pretty new to coding so any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Give me a second I write you some examples.  Just a question, the form is intended to be in the same page or in another page?

Comment: The form will be on the same page. It's loaded in a lightbox when a user clicks the 'Remind Me' link.

Comment: The way i'm selecting the products from the database makes iterating through them a bit tricky. (I'm selecting the top 3 products by release date, followed by all products for that release date, then loop through for all release dates). Is it possible to put the PHP variable (title for example) into `a href` ID or name and pass that through to the form?